# Datatrigger auto reverse color

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, wpf-style

I want to change the background color to red instantly if a property is true. Then revert slowly back to default background color.

My first attempt, problem: Default color appears instantly and not reverting slowly over time

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValueChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValueChanged}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0:0:5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
```

My second attempt, problem: Color reverses like it should, but never goes red again if the property remains true

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValueChanged}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation To="Red" AutoReverse="True"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0:0:5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't set a Timeline's `FillBehavior` to `Stop`, it keeps holding the final property value until it is replaced by another Timeline.

So this works:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValueChanged}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                To="Red" Duration="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                From="Red" Duration="0:0:1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Except that previous Triggers for IsFocused etc. which changes the background color too, kills this animation when HasValueChanged remains true which is odd. My current workaround is setting HasValueChanged to false manually and set it back to true but that doesn't seem to be a good solution.